# Flutter BlocListener how to call events from another bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I can't figure out whats allowed to use and what shouldn't be done. From web im reading:

> BLOCLISTENER BlocListener is a Flutter widget that takes a
> BlocWidgetListener and an optional bloc and calls the listener when
> the state of the bloc changes. It should be used for functionality
> that only happens once per state change, such as navigation,
> displaying a SnackBar, displaying a dialog, and so on.
>
> BlocListener will automatically conduct a lookup using BlocProvider
> and the current BuildContext if the bloc parameter is omitted.

Now I have a quite complex app structure and I need to call 2 Events from another bloc. This is my code:

```
return BlocListener<LiveeventsBloc, LiveeventsState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
        if (state is LiveeventFinishedState) {
          print('LiveeventFinishedState');
          BlocProvider.of<EventsBloc>(context).add(LoadJoinableEvent()); // Event from another bloc
          BlocProvider.of<EventsBloc>(context).add(LoadEventsEvent()); // Event from another bloc
        }
      },
```

Now Im not sure, can I call events from another bloc now? It's not clear to me what is allowed to do. The first event is fetching data and providing a button in UI depending on the result, the second event is fetching data and displaying it.

Comment: You may have a problem that if you change the state (the first time) it’ll recall the listener again, then repeat forever. Just a thought

Comment: when the user is moving back to the given screen where im showing the piece of code, i am not able to get my data from the server if im removing those event calls. above this file in my widget tree im loading them with ..add(), but it only works on initial app load. if the user navigates away and comes back to the screen i dont have the data

Comment: You can reload the data when returning to the screen, the Navigator is a Future, but you can also call events from block a on block b.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you mean the above code is fine?